# Equality operator in favour of std.range.equal

Tags: comparison, range, d

I'm curious to why D developers promote use of `std.range.equal` in cases such as

```
bool isPalindrome(Range)(in Range range) if 
(isBidirectionalRange!Range)
{
    return range.retro.equal(range);
}
```

Why isn't equality operator `==` used here instead?

See also: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/qdamjxisavsizvrdpecf@forum.dlang.org#post-qdamjxisavsizvrdpecf:40forum.dlang.org

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equality operator is for comparing objects of the same type, whereas ranges frequently have drastically different types.

```
auto result = range1.equal(range2);
```

will compare the two input ranges regardless of what types they are as long as their elements may be compared, whereas

```
auto result = range1 == range2;
```

would require that the two ranges be of the same type, which is rarely the case. At present, there are even many cases where two ranges which *should* be considered the same type aren't, because the language is unable to compare lambda functions to see whether they're the same function (a serious downside to moving away from string lambdas as we have been, since strings *can* be compared for equality). Hopefully, this will be remedied in the future, but it does often make comparing ranges with `==` difficult even if you wanted to.

Also, `==` is not among the set of operations supported by the range API. `range1 == range2` will compile if the two ranges are of the same type (since `==` is defined for all types), but they could be comparing reference equality or be doing a deeper comparison. It would depend entirely on the range's implementation. All that's required of input ranges is that this code compile:

```
{
    R r = void;       // can define a range object
    if (r.empty) {}   // can test for empty
    r.popFront();     // can invoke popFront()
    auto h = r.front; // can get the front of the range
}
```

where `R` is the range type. No other requirements are put on input ranges. So, you can't rely on `==` working for them, whereas `equal` uses the input range API to do its comparison and thus will work with all input ranges with elements which can be compared.